# Getting an error running dotCover from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, dotcover

I am trying to add a task to our build pipeline in **Azure DevOps** to calculate our code coverage using the **dotCover** commandline tool. However, I am getting the following error.

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.RunnerCommandline.Runner.Main(String[]
>   args)

I have added a reference to the assembly **Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common** to our tests project and have set *Copy Local* to true so it gets copied into the *bin* folder.

Here is my command for executing **dotCover** (I have added **dotCover** and **MSTEST** to our project so we can run it from **Azure DevOps**).

> dotCover.exe analyse 
>   /TargetExecutable="Tools\MSTest\MSTest.exe"
>   /TargetArguments="/testcontainer:\MyServices.Tests\bin\MyServices.Tests.dll"
>   /Output="output.html" /ReportType="HTML"

**UPDATE 09.10.2019**

Here is the reference to the assembly in my .csproj. I have added a reference to v15 of the assembly.

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Getting an error running dotCover from Azure DevOps

Aswe know, the assembly `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common` is part of Visual Studio.

When you add the assembly `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common` to your tests project, you will get following in your project file `.csproj`:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Even if you set `Copy Local` to `true` to get it copied into the bin folder. But the `\bin` folder is ignored by default by the `.gitignore`/`.tfignore`. When you build the project with Azure devops, it will still search the dll file from PublicAssemblies folder.

If we do not install Visual Studio 2015 on the build agent machine, we will not found it.

So, to resolve this issue, you need to install the Visual Studio 2015 on the build agent machine, then check if there is `PublicAssemblies` folder uder IDE, then check if the file `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll` exist or not.

Besides, if you do not want to install Visual Studio 2015 on the build agent machine, you could copy that `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll` from the `PublicAssemblies` folder to the project/solution folder, then add it as reference instead of from `PublicAssemblies` folder, then you will get following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>.\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then, add this `.dll` file into the source control and submit it to the Azure repos.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll give that a go and see what happens.

Comment: @DomBurf, Anytime, let me know the latest status about this issue for free, I will keep follow it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to clarify, I have added a reference to the file to the project. I have set Copy Local to true so that it gets copied into the bin folder. The file is definitely in the bin folder of my tests project. But for some reason, dotCover is complaining that it can't find the file. This is an Azure DevOps hosted build so I don't have the option of installing Visual Studio.

Comment: @DomBurf, Which Azure devops hosted agent you are using? You can use the Hosted (vs2015-win2012r2) to build your project, which with Visual Studio 2015 installed" https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2015-Server2012R2-Readme.md And if it not help you, you can still try my another workaround in my answer.

Comment: I'm using the VS2017 Azure host for my build. Whereabouts will will VS2017 be installed on the host?

Comment: @DomBurf, If you are using VS2017 hosted agent, you will get that error, because the version of that reference of VS2017 is 15.0, but you add the reference is 14.0, so, you need to change the reference version to 15.0, reference it from vs2017 instead of VS2015.

Comment: @DomBurf, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error unfortunately. I have tried using both v14 and 15 of the assembly but the problem persists.

Comment: @DomBurf, please share the reference info in your .csproj file about that 15.0 version reference in your question, and if you use 15.0, you still have the error that Could not load file or assembly 14.0? Share more info what have you done and the error info, thanks.

Comment: I have updated my question with the .csproj reference. I get the same error whether I use v14 or 15 i.e. Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException